# twitter mining Memory error

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, mining

I am doing twitter mining where I am dealing with large amount of data .I am getting Memory error in my below code -

```
    ids_str = ','.join([str(_id) for _id in ids[:100]])
    ids = ids[100:] <--------- this point has memory error .
```

where ids dict has around 12.5 Million entries . what could be the issue here could you please suggest.?

Comment: Also please suggest what should I use instead of above .

Comment: I guess `ids` is actually a list. If you're trying to generate strings for each 100 of ids you could use something like `for s in range(0, len(ids), 100)` and then use `ids[s:s + 100]` without clipping the list.